# Possible with one script in IBM DB2 to set all tables to GENERATED BY DEFAULT?

Tags: db2

I would need to set all tables' primary key column temporarily to GENERATED BY DEFAULT instead of ALWAYS. I can ofcourse compile a list myself, but is it possible with "one go" to set this for all tables in a specific schema? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Perhaps there is another solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Mainframe DB2, then this command should work for you (this assumes you mean the key is an Identity column, generated always, there are other codes for defaults, which you can see on the [Info Center page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsyscolumnstable.htm)):

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' ||
    RTRIM(TBCREATOR) || '.' || RTRIM(TBNAME) ||
    'ALTER COLUMN ' ||
    RTRIM(NAME) ||
    'SET GENERATED BY DEFAULT;'
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE DEFAULT = 'I'
  AND TBCREATOR = @schema
```

If you're on DB2 for LUW, then this should do it:

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' ||
    RTRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '.' || RTRIM(TABNAME) ||
    'ALTER COLUMN ' ||
    RTRIM(COLNAME) ||
    'SET GENERATED BY DEFAULT;'
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE GENERATED = 'A'
  AND TABSCHEMA = @schema
```

This will only generate the commands needed. You will need to execute them yourself.

Comment: I'm running DB2 9.7 on Linux. So your queries above, do they actually execute the alter statements, or does it just return them?

Comment: This will only generate the commands you have to run. Sorry about that, I thought I included that part in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the query by querying the data from the catalog. I mean, you make a Select that returns the alter command, and this output is send to a file. After you just have to execute the content of that file

(Linux/UNIX/Cywgin)

```
db2 -x "select 'alter table ' || trim(tabschema) || '.' || trim(tabname) || ' alter column ' || colname || ' set generated by default as identity ;' from syscat.columns where tabschema like 'DB2INS%' and keyseq >= 0" > test.sql
db2 -tvf file.sql
```

However, you have to check the generated commands, and if executed, check the returned values:

```
db2 create table t1 \(c1 int not null primary key, c2 int, c3 int\)
db2 create table t2 \(c21 int references t1 \(c1\), c22 int\)
db2 create table t3 \(c30 int, c31 int not null, c32 int not null, c33 int\)
db2 alter table t3 add primary key \(c31, c32\)
db2 create table t4 \(c40 int, c41 int, c42 int, c43 int\)
db2 alter table t4 add constraint fk foreign key \(c42, c43\) references t3

db2 -x "select 'alter table ' || trim(tabschema) || '.' || trim(tabname) || ' alter column ' || colname || ' set generated by default as identity ;' from syscat.columns where tabschema like 'DB2INS%' and keyseq >= 0" > test.sql

db2 -tvf test.sql
alter table DB2INS01.T1 alter column C1 set generated by default as identity
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
alter table DB2INS01.T3 alter column C31 set generated by default as identity
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
alter table DB2INS01.T3 alter column C32 set generated by default as identity
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0372N  A column with data type or attribute ROWID, IDENTITY, security label,
or row change timestamp can only be specified once for a table.
SQLSTATE=428C1
```